# Using Qt to implement a C++ HTTPS SOAP client on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, soap, https

After having some issues using OpenSSL and gSOAP, I have been looking into the use of other options for the HTTPS transport mechanism for SOAP requests. Something that caught my eye was `QNetworkRequest` that I believe is part of Qt. I have never used Qt before but from the research I have done I get the impression that it is geared towards the development of GUI applications. My application is not a GUI, so my question is **is it possible for me to access the functionality of QNetworkRequest outside of the Qt development environment ?**. Is it possible via linking to an appropriate library and appropriate header file inclusions or must I develop a full blown application inside the Qt IDE in order to access the functionality? If I have to import my project into the Qt IDE then this option is not for me so before I spend weeks reading manuals and web tutorials I would like to see if experienced users of Qt can tell me if what I want is possible or if I need to look elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general GUI frameworks are highly coupled; especially those written in C++.

I'm sure you could decouple `QNetworkRequest`, but it would probably take a long time to do.

If you use a different library which has the functionality you're after (e.g.: [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/)) you'll be much better off.

Comment: This is what I feared. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you're still interested in going ahead with the decoupling, check the [diploma thesis](http://peter.hartmann.tk/work/a-soap-stack-for-the-qt-framework.pdf) from which the SOAP implementation came from. Chapter 5 shows the dependencies best. Chapter 4 will give an overview of other kits (including gSOAP).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look but probably will just try to integrate my project into a new Qt application. Hope it is worth it.